# GitLab CI/CD doesn't allow to push code after authentication with SSH

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, cicd

I’m trying to make a job that merges to TEST branch after merging to master, but I’m having problems with pushing code to the repository.

Heres the code:

```
deploy_test:
  stage: deploy
  image: ubuntu:latest
  tags:
    - docker-bind
  script:
    - apt-get update -y
    - apt-get install -y git openssh-client
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - chmod 600 "$SSH_KEY"
    - ssh-add "$SSH_KEY"
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh

    - git config user.email <email>
    - git config user.name <name>

    - ssh-keyscan <host> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
    
    - git checkout $TEST_BRANCH
    - git merge origin/master
    - git push origin $TEST_BRANCH
  environment:
    name: testing
    url: <url>
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

The job dies at git push and throws the following error:

```
remote: You are not allowed to upload code.
```

The SSH key is valid, because it’s my personal one which I use for development. I have maintainer access, so I’m confused as to why it doesn’t allow me to push code.

Comment: Are you sure the code is cloned using SSH? If the CI Job clones the repo using HTTPS than all your work to setup ssh keys is not having any effect